# Change colors of the folders in platformio-ide-terminal

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I just installed this package for the Atom editor and I want to change the colors of the folders that I see in terminal.

E.G

When I do `ls` command from atom's terminal I see some folders with green color some folders I see with blue color which is hard to read on a black backround.

I want to change all to green. I have looked around in the settings but was not able to change it.

I also googled and saw that one should edit some file in order to do this change, but I did not find the file in which I'm supposed to do that change.

Please help me change this

Answer (score 4):

Here is the **step by step** Simple solution-

1- Go to packages-> Platormio-ide-terminal(or install if not)

2- Go under **Ansi Colors Z Bright**, now Change **2nd Option i.e., Bright Blue**

[image]

3- Reload Terminal/Atom, and you will see difference-

[image]

Comment: stress that reload is needed.  i fumbled for a bit trying to figure out why it's not changing.

Answer (score 1):

the things are defined in the extension you loaded. In this case the platformio-ide-terminal extension. From inside Atom, click Preferences under the Atom menu. that will bring up a settings pane where you then click on Packages which appears on the left side of that pane. Input Platformio Ide Terminal and that should bring up a set of tabs labeled Settings, Uninstall, and Disable. Click on Settings. the pane will change to the platformio-ide-terminal pane. You can scroll down and find settings for things like the colors to use.